# How do I stop DataGrip being so index picky?

Tags: sap-ase, jetbrains-ide, unique-index, datagrip

I am trying to get a new machine up and running and have been told to install JetBrains DataGrip.

Having installed it, however, there are some tables for which this error message keeps appearing:

> The optimizer could not find a unique index which it could use to scan
>   table [...] for cursor [...]

I appreciate that this means the table does not have a unique index but I am not going to go and ensure every table in the whole system has a unique index. Is there a way around this please, apart from not using Datagrip...?

Comment: I am doing a simple select: `SELECT * FROM FGR_db_Local..tb_Ferry`, this is Sybase SQL

Comment: That sounds more like an error coming from the database, rather than from DataGrip. Does your SELECT work with other tools?

Comment: Every other tool - SQLBrowser or Aqua Data Studio for example.

Comment: It also works with direct Linux SQL coding, so the SQL is written as a procedure and run using a Linux SQL coder. I would very much rather not have to do it this way...

Comment: Do you know if the driver DataGrip is using differs from the driver that the other clients are using?

Comment: I'm afraid that I have no idea. Sorry - not much use.